# Best way to stop more inputs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Lets suppose I want someone to only be able to enter one  input at a time, EX: would be .... lets say I want only one tea for 1.80 and every time they hit tea after 1.80 is sent to the txtBox, nothing else would appear. What would be the best way to compile this the most efficient way. Keyword: efficient.

EDIT: I am not asking for code, so before smashing the negative point arrow, please keep in mind I am asking for ideas and not code. This isn't a "show me how to do this" -  it is what would you recommend in words and not actual code.

EDIT:: AGAIN:: Specifically I am looking for better way to do this. THIS CODE does work. It only allows me to enter it once. I am only wanting to know a more efficient way to do this.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    string c;
    double num1;
    double num2;
    private bool inputStatus = true;

    private void Coffee_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text += 3.00;
    }
    private void Tea_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text += 1.80;
    }
    private void Cream_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text += .15;
    }
    private void Total_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double Total;
        num2 = double.Parse(txtBox.Text);

        switch (c)
        {
            case "+":
                Total = num1 + num2;
                txtBox.Text = Total.ToString();
                num1 = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
    private void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        num1 = num1 + double.Parse(txtBox.Text);
        c = "+";
        txtBox.Clear();
    }
    private void Cinnamon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (inputStatus)
        {
            if (txtBox.Text.Length <= 1)
            {
                txtBox.Text += .30;
            }
        }
    }
    private void Sugar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text += .50;
    }

    private void Whippedcream_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text += .70;
    }
    private void Clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Clear();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You'll avoid the "smashing negative arrow" writing an in-depth Question. See the guide [ask] and its linked articles.

Comment: @brasofilo I updated my code with a quick generic way I knew how to do.  I am just wanting ot know if there is a better way to do it. As far as my fault, no I did not read how to ask an in-depth question. I did not know it was that strict.

Comment: Well, it's a fantastic site/network *because* it is quality oriented. Good luck with your Q, I don't know C#, just wanted to give a hint.

Comment: Please don't consider it as harshness - downvotes aren't necessarily a bad thing http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote, specifically "voting down a post signals the opposite: that the post contains wrong information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate information." It's merely an indicator that something might need to change.

Comment: Although, it certainly wouldn't hurt you at all to accept some previous answers on your questions.

Answer (score 2):

A Quick thought :  After a item button is clicked make only the add/clear/total button enabled. All other item buttons will be disabled. Therefore the only possibility is to click on the enabled buttons. After the add/clear/total button is clicked then just make all other item buttons enabled.

Create a private method:

```
private void DisableEnableAllItemButtons(bool state) 
{ 
  btn1.enabled=state; 
  btn2.enabled=state; 
  /* and so on */  
}
```

This method will change the buttons' enabled/disaled state depending on the `state` parameter. In click event handler of all item buttons call DisableEnableAllItemButtons(false), then make only add/clear/total buttons enabled. You can also create another method to enable/disable add/clear/total buttons as we did for item buttons.

Answer (score 2):

Use a radio button showing your options as tea, coffee ...and the value pass the values. In this way only one selection/input is possible. Make a post back on radio button selection.

Answer (score 1):

Consider writing a class (or set of classes) that maintains the state of the beverage. After all, the state of the beverage really shouldn't be the concern of the form (besides how to display it). It becomes simple to update your form's state based upon the beverage's state.

Consider a set of classes like this:

```
public interface IBeverage { 
  double Price { get; } 
}

public abstract class Beverage : IBeverage {
  public abstract double Price { get; }
}

public class Coffee : Beverage { 
  public override double Price {
    get {
      return 3.00;
    }
  }
}

public class Tea : Beverage { 
  public override double Price {
    get {
      return 2.00;
    }
  }
}

public class Cream : Beverage { 
  public override double Price { 
    get { 
      return .15;
    }
  }
}
```

They are a pretty simplistic representation of coffee, tea, and cream (the examples in your question). With a representation of the beverages that is separate from your form, you can have another class that manages state for you:

```
public class BeverageManager { 
  private List<Beverage> _beverage = new List<Beverage>();
  private List<Type> _types = new List<Type>();
  private HashSet<Type> _multipleAllows = new HashSet<Type>();

  public BeverageManager(Type[] multipleAllows) {  
    foreach (var allowed in multipleAllows)
      _multipleAllows.Add(allowed); 
  }

  public double Price { 
    get { 
      return (from bev in _beverage
              select bev.Price).Sum();
    }
  }

  public bool HasType(Type t) { 
    return _types.Contains(t); 
  }

  public bool AddBeverage(Beverage bev) { 
    if (HasType(bev.GetType()) && !_multipleAllows.Contains(bev.GetType()))
      return false; 
    _types.Add(bev.GetType()); 
    _beverage.Add(bev); 
    return true; 
  }
}
```

Why go through all this trouble just to keep your form's enabled/disabled states in order? Because your form doesn't have to care about managing the state of what it's displaying. With this implementation, you can have code like this:

```
private void _updateFormState() { 
  if (_bevMgr.HasType(typeof(Coffee) || typeof(Tea)) { 
    // disable coffee and tea buttons
  }
}
```

And, if you find yourself needing to migrate the beverage tracker (or whatever it is exactly you are programming :D), you don't have to write all the state management code again.

**Please note:** My implementation is to show the concept of state management and separation of responsibility. It isn't particularly extensible (if you later needed to add a new type of drink, for example, would require writing code). A more probable solution would involve loading data about beverages from a database or other source and writing a beverage manager to handle that scenario - however why having this functionality separate would remain a good idea for the same reason.